# Use two queries to populate table with INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Could someone elucidate for me why the following does not work:

```
insert into DrugInteractions(ndc_fk, ndc_pk)
   (select top 1 ndc from DrugList where drug_name like 'cipro%'),
   (select top 1 ndc from DrugList where drug_name like 'tizan%')
```

The column `ndc` in `DrugList` is a primary key which uniquely identifies a certain drug.  Since you need two things to interact the `DrugInteractions` table has two copies of the `ndc`; these two `ndc`s will be a composite primary key.  So say Drug A has an ndc of 1 and Drug B has an ndc of 2, then the row in DrugInteraction would look like:

```
ndc_pk   ndc_fk
1        2
```

Is there a way to populate a table using an insert statement with two queries, one for each column like I'm trying?  The error I get is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ','

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `VALUES` to combine them;

```
insert into DrugInteractions(ndc_fk,ndc_pk)
VALUES(
  (select top 1 ndc from DrugList where drug_name like 'cipro%'),
  (select top 1 ndc from DrugList where drug_name like 'tizan%')
)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5db86/2).

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into DrugInteractions(ndc_fk, ndc_pk)
   select top 1 ndc, newid() from DrugList where drug_name like 'cipro%'
   union
   select top 1 ndc, newid() from DrugList where drug_name like 'tizan%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to running multiple select statements:

```
insert into DrugInteractions (ndc_fk, ndc_pk) 
select min(case when drug_name like 'cipro%' then ndc end),
  min(case when drug_name like 'tizan%' then ndc end)
from DrugList
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dffa/1)